# NodeJs data merge inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have following api data:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK",
    "result": [
        {
            "blockNumber": "14376792",
            "timeStamp": "1642218997",
            "hash": "0xe7a8a5793d1e85ec6f6de891f8be9bee2bf455b086236a98365be00febb8dec9",
            "nonce": "852",
            "blockHash": "0x45b51bbac31bd1aef3215db88d05faa1172f9b9b7cb1f8f570b67e0bcef4e954",
            "from": "0x6d038b92c6aa2fc4db2ca80dc9dc5d63ddafe33d",
            "contractAddress": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "to": "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
            "value": "72405000000000000000",
            "tokenName": "Andromeda V2",
            "tokenSymbol": "M31",
            "tokenDecimal": "18",
            "transactionIndex": "25",
            "gas": "266039",
            "gasPrice": "6000000000",
            "gasUsed": "201266",
            "cumulativeGasUsed": "2552933",
            "input": "deprecated",
            "confirmations": "670"
        },
        {
            "blockNumber": "14376072",
            "timeStamp": "1642216837",
            "hash": "0x3ffe38506478a3a81ac39933d46521aa0624cd8b89bc36f79f20c2d0b81c5f92",
            "nonce": "9",
            "blockHash": "0x672eeba6792d41c298057fefd3a31b1ab8acf8b877d8ef3f4c790234f3b4dd1b",
            "from": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "contractAddress": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "to": "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
            "value": "1917760707567583701190",
            "tokenName": "Andromeda V2",
            "tokenSymbol": "M31",
            "tokenDecimal": "18",
            "transactionIndex": "102",
            "gas": "433404",
            "gasPrice": "5000000000",
            "gasUsed": "350916",
            "cumulativeGasUsed": "17811460",
            "input": "deprecated",
            "confirmations": "1390"
        },
        {
            "blockNumber": "14375679",
            "timeStamp": "1642215658",
            "hash": "0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da",
            "nonce": "5",
            "blockHash": "0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517",
            "from": "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
            "contractAddress": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "to": "0x7345c01c595d69a02c95d65551499c67ae3edf4f",
            "value": "620431183157188467115",
            "tokenName": "Andromeda V2",
            "tokenSymbol": "M31",
            "tokenDecimal": "18",
            "transactionIndex": "171",
            "gas": "215186",
            "gasPrice": "5000000000",
            "gasUsed": "169374",
            "cumulativeGasUsed": "34069029",
            "input": "deprecated",
            "confirmations": "1783"
        },
        {
            "blockNumber": "14375679",
            "timeStamp": "1642215658",
            "hash": "0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da",
            "nonce": "5",
            "blockHash": "0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517",
            "from": "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
            "contractAddress": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "to": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "value": "68936798128576496346",
            "tokenName": "Andromeda V2",
            "tokenSymbol": "M31",
            "tokenDecimal": "18",
            "transactionIndex": "171",
            "gas": "215186",
            "gasPrice": "5000000000",
            "gasUsed": "169374",
            "cumulativeGasUsed": "34069029",
            "input": "deprecated",
            "confirmations": "1783"
        },
        {
            "blockNumber": "14375177",
            "timeStamp": "1642214152",
            "hash": "0x3d499ef6fe397cf121608aaff9a1c02e863fdacd41afea946f548f1f38c630df",
            "nonce": "563",
            "blockHash": "0xdceb19ad995f0cd0aae6e911744be3c6d3bf81b9e707e710bf0f06f6c1379030",
            "from": "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
            "contractAddress": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "to": "0x6d4d24e50c1bad7df10fafb979de12b6cc6cdac8",
            "value": "1023172053263716043052",
            "tokenName": "Andromeda V2",
            "tokenSymbol": "M31",
            "tokenDecimal": "18",
            "transactionIndex": "93",
            "gas": "215186",
            "gasPrice": "5000000000",
            "gasUsed": "169374",
            "cumulativeGasUsed": "12183067",
            "input": "deprecated",
            "confirmations": "2285"
        }
    ]
}
```

Two rows of this data has same `hash` id `0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da` (you can search it yourself) I want to merge some variables in this 2 rows to become one.

`Here is the logic:`

If rows hash are same merge (sum) `value` data.

My current code is like:

```
if(myData[id].length > 0) {
    for (let i in myData[id]) {
        const number = myData[id][i].value;
        // other values.....
        console.log('values is: ', number);
        // doing something with result
    }
}
```

Sample code above return value of each row in API but as I mentioned I need to sum `value` of rows with same hash.

`Crystal clear`

Based on sample API above I have `5` rows, I need to get `4` rows. One of them which data are summed up from the 2 rows with same `hash`.

#### Update

`expected result` (commented)

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK",
    "result": [
     // other...
     {
            "blockNumber": "14375679",
            "timeStamp": "1642215658",
            "hash": "0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da",
            "nonce": "5",
            "blockHash": "0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517",
            "from": "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
            "contractAddress": "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
            "to": "0x7345c01c595d69a02c95d65551499c67ae3edf4f",
            "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",   //<<-------- This value will be sum of the 2 rows value with same hash
            "tokenName": "Andromeda V2",
            "tokenSymbol": "M31",
            "tokenDecimal": "18",
            "transactionIndex": "171",
            "gas": "215186",
            "gasPrice": "5000000000",
            "gasUsed": "169374",
            "cumulativeGasUsed": "34069029",
            "input": "deprecated",
            "confirmations": "1783"
    },
    // other...
};
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: so objects with same hash will become one object ?

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAkram exactly

Comment: There must be `4` end result objects because only one ID matches with `hash`...

Comment: @decpk you're right should be 4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solved

I've commented each part for better understanding.

**Final code**

```
data.result = _(data.result)
.groupBy('hash').map(function(v, k) {
    //mapping values of each row to arrays ['1000', '2000']
    var myValue =  _.map(v, 'value');

    // if array includes more than one number (means there was same hash) then convert them to number array instead of string array (future calculation purpose)
    if(myValue.length > 1){
      var convertToNumberArray = Array.from(myValue,Number); // [1000, 2000]
    } else {
      var convertToNumberArray = myValue;
    }
    // return merged data and summed values
    return {
        ...v[0],
        value: ''+_.sum(convertToNumberArray)+''
    } 
}).value();
```

**Here is how it looks after code above:**

```
Output:

[
  {
    blockNumber: '14376792',
    timeStamp: '1642218997',
    hash: '0xe7a8a5793d1e85ec6f6de891f8be9bee2bf455b086236a98365be00febb8dec9',
    nonce: '852',
    blockHash: '0x45b51bbac31bd1aef3215db88d05faa1172f9b9b7cb1f8f570b67e0bcef4e954',
    from: '0x6d038b92c6aa2fc4db2ca80dc9dc5d63ddafe33d',
    contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
    to: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
    value: '72405000000000000000',
    tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
    tokenSymbol: 'M31',
    tokenDecimal: '18',
    transactionIndex: '25',
    gas: '266039',
    gasPrice: '6000000000',
    gasUsed: '201266',
    cumulativeGasUsed: '2552933',
    input: 'deprecated',
    confirmations: '670'
  },
  {
    blockNumber: '14376072',
    timeStamp: '1642216837',
    hash: '0x3ffe38506478a3a81ac39933d46521aa0624cd8b89bc36f79f20c2d0b81c5f92',
    nonce: '9',
    blockHash: '0x672eeba6792d41c298057fefd3a31b1ab8acf8b877d8ef3f4c790234f3b4dd1b',
    from: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
    contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
    to: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
    value: '1917760707567583701190',
    tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
    tokenSymbol: 'M31',
    tokenDecimal: '18',
    transactionIndex: '102',
    gas: '433404',
    gasPrice: '5000000000',
    gasUsed: '350916',
    cumulativeGasUsed: '17811460',
    input: 'deprecated',
    confirmations: '1390'
  },
  {
    blockNumber: '14375679',
    timeStamp: '1642215658',
    hash: '0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da',
    nonce: '5',
    blockHash: '0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517',
    from: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
    contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
    to: '0x7345c01c595d69a02c95d65551499c67ae3edf4f',
    value: '689367981285765000000', // <-- value was summed up
    tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
    tokenSymbol: 'M31',
    tokenDecimal: '18',
    transactionIndex: '171',
    gas: '215186',
    gasPrice: '5000000000',
    gasUsed: '169374',
    cumulativeGasUsed: '34069029',
    input: 'deprecated',
    confirmations: '1783'
  },
  {
    blockNumber: '14375177',
    timeStamp: '1642214152',
    hash: '0x3d499ef6fe397cf121608aaff9a1c02e863fdacd41afea946f548f1f38c630df',
    nonce: '563',
    blockHash: '0xdceb19ad995f0cd0aae6e911744be3c6d3bf81b9e707e710bf0f06f6c1379030',
    from: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
    contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
    to: '0x6d4d24e50c1bad7df10fafb979de12b6cc6cdac8',
    value: '1023172053263716043052',
    tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
    tokenSymbol: 'M31',
    tokenDecimal: '18',
    transactionIndex: '93',
    gas: '215186',
    gasPrice: '5000000000',
    gasUsed: '169374',
    cumulativeGasUsed: '12183067',
    input: 'deprecated',
    confirmations: '2285'
  }
]
```

Comment: Since you copied my answer and answered your own question, could you please mark my answer as the accepted one?

Comment: @VasylBoroviak since your answer uses mapValues and sumBy which I don't use in my solution then NO.

Comment: Weird. But my code outputs exactly the same data as yours. My code is simply shorter. But ok. I get it. Have a good code!

Comment: Don't get me wrong please, I appreciate that you tried to help all I'm saying is that your code wasn't the one I used to solve my issue, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Maphttps://) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) here as:

```js
const data = {
  status: '1',
  message: 'OK',
  result: [
    {
      blockNumber: '14376792',
      timeStamp: '1642218997',
      hash: '0xe7a8a5793d1e85ec6f6de891f8be9bee2bf455b086236a98365be00febb8dec9',
      nonce: '852',
      blockHash:
        '0x45b51bbac31bd1aef3215db88d05faa1172f9b9b7cb1f8f570b67e0bcef4e954',
      from: '0x6d038b92c6aa2fc4db2ca80dc9dc5d63ddafe33d',
      contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      to: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
      value: '72405000000000000000',
      tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
      tokenSymbol: 'M31',
      tokenDecimal: '18',
      transactionIndex: '25',
      gas: '266039',
      gasPrice: '6000000000',
      gasUsed: '201266',
      cumulativeGasUsed: '2552933',
      input: 'deprecated',
      confirmations: '670',
    },
    {
      blockNumber: '14376072',
      timeStamp: '1642216837',
      hash: '0x3ffe38506478a3a81ac39933d46521aa0624cd8b89bc36f79f20c2d0b81c5f92',
      nonce: '9',
      blockHash:
        '0x672eeba6792d41c298057fefd3a31b1ab8acf8b877d8ef3f4c790234f3b4dd1b',
      from: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      to: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
      value: '1917760707567583701190',
      tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
      tokenSymbol: 'M31',
      tokenDecimal: '18',
      transactionIndex: '102',
      gas: '433404',
      gasPrice: '5000000000',
      gasUsed: '350916',
      cumulativeGasUsed: '17811460',
      input: 'deprecated',
      confirmations: '1390',
    },
    {
      blockNumber: '14375679',
      timeStamp: '1642215658',
      hash: '0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da',
      nonce: '5',
      blockHash:
        '0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517',
      from: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
      contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      to: '0x7345c01c595d69a02c95d65551499c67ae3edf4f',
      value: '620431183157188467115',
      tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
      tokenSymbol: 'M31',
      tokenDecimal: '18',
      transactionIndex: '171',
      gas: '215186',
      gasPrice: '5000000000',
      gasUsed: '169374',
      cumulativeGasUsed: '34069029',
      input: 'deprecated',
      confirmations: '1783',
    },
    {
      blockNumber: '14375679',
      timeStamp: '1642215658',
      hash: '0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da',
      nonce: '5',
      blockHash:
        '0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517',
      from: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
      contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      to: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      value: '68936798128576496346',
      tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
      tokenSymbol: 'M31',
      tokenDecimal: '18',
      transactionIndex: '171',
      gas: '215186',
      gasPrice: '5000000000',
      gasUsed: '169374',
      cumulativeGasUsed: '34069029',
      input: 'deprecated',
      confirmations: '1783',
    },
    {
      blockNumber: '14375177',
      timeStamp: '1642214152',
      hash: '0x3d499ef6fe397cf121608aaff9a1c02e863fdacd41afea946f548f1f38c630df',
      nonce: '563',
      blockHash:
        '0xdceb19ad995f0cd0aae6e911744be3c6d3bf81b9e707e710bf0f06f6c1379030',
      from: '0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6',
      contractAddress: '0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414',
      to: '0x6d4d24e50c1bad7df10fafb979de12b6cc6cdac8',
      value: '1023172053263716043052',
      tokenName: 'Andromeda V2',
      tokenSymbol: 'M31',
      tokenDecimal: '18',
      transactionIndex: '93',
      gas: '215186',
      gasPrice: '5000000000',
      gasUsed: '169374',
      cumulativeGasUsed: '12183067',
      input: 'deprecated',
      confirmations: '2285',
    },
  ],
};

const map = new Map();
data.result.forEach((o) => {
  map.has(o.hash)
    ? map.set(o.hash, { ...map.get(o.hash), ...o })
    : map.set(o.hash, o);
});

data.result = [...map.values()];
console.log(data);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: give me some time to test it please.

Comment: I just realised, is this code update my myData[id] results? so I don't need to make any changes in my loop part? (how does it sum my value values?)

Comment: as much as i see it ignores one of duplicated hashes and just return one of them but it does not handle sum functionality.

Comment: what do you mean by `handle sum functionality`? Please be clear and add the expected result in the question itself...

Comment: please read `Here is the logic:` and `Crystal clear` part in my question.

Comment: this 2 values have to be summed up `"value": "620431183157188467115",
"value": "68936798128576496346",`

Comment: added expected result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  status: "1",
  message: "OK",
  result: [
    {
      blockNumber: "14376792",
      timeStamp: "1642218997",
      hash:
        "0xe7a8a5793d1e85ec6f6de891f8be9bee2bf455b086236a98365be00febb8dec9",
      nonce: "852",
      blockHash:
        "0x45b51bbac31bd1aef3215db88d05faa1172f9b9b7cb1f8f570b67e0bcef4e954",
      from: "0x6d038b92c6aa2fc4db2ca80dc9dc5d63ddafe33d",
      contractAddress: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      to: "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
      value: "72405000000000000000",
      tokenName: "Andromeda V2",
      tokenSymbol: "M31",
      tokenDecimal: "18",
      transactionIndex: "25",
      gas: "266039",
      gasPrice: "6000000000",
      gasUsed: "201266",
      cumulativeGasUsed: "2552933",
      input: "deprecated",
      confirmations: "670"
    },
    {
      blockNumber: "14376072",
      timeStamp: "1642216837",
      hash:
        "0x3ffe38506478a3a81ac39933d46521aa0624cd8b89bc36f79f20c2d0b81c5f92",
      nonce: "9",
      blockHash:
        "0x672eeba6792d41c298057fefd3a31b1ab8acf8b877d8ef3f4c790234f3b4dd1b",
      from: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      contractAddress: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      to: "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
      value: "1917760707567583701190",
      tokenName: "Andromeda V2",
      tokenSymbol: "M31",
      tokenDecimal: "18",
      transactionIndex: "102",
      gas: "433404",
      gasPrice: "5000000000",
      gasUsed: "350916",
      cumulativeGasUsed: "17811460",
      input: "deprecated",
      confirmations: "1390"
    },
    {
      blockNumber: "14375679",
      timeStamp: "1642215658",
      hash:
        "0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da",
      nonce: "5",
      blockHash:
        "0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517",
      from: "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
      contractAddress: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      to: "0x7345c01c595d69a02c95d65551499c67ae3edf4f",
      value: "620431183157188467115",
      tokenName: "Andromeda V2",
      tokenSymbol: "M31",
      tokenDecimal: "18",
      transactionIndex: "171",
      gas: "215186",
      gasPrice: "5000000000",
      gasUsed: "169374",
      cumulativeGasUsed: "34069029",
      input: "deprecated",
      confirmations: "1783"
    },
    {
      blockNumber: "14375679",
      timeStamp: "1642215658",
      hash:
        "0x433638955630652e6263f14dd3322668eafe447de5ad26664a307d8283c593da",
      nonce: "5",
      blockHash:
        "0x5ab95c904b703b5b197758772bcadefa7464f2ba4528c2e9615961199ac41517",
      from: "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
      contractAddress: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      to: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      value: "68936798128576496346",
      tokenName: "Andromeda V2",
      tokenSymbol: "M31",
      tokenDecimal: "18",
      transactionIndex: "171",
      gas: "215186",
      gasPrice: "5000000000",
      gasUsed: "169374",
      cumulativeGasUsed: "34069029",
      input: "deprecated",
      confirmations: "1783"
    },
    {
      blockNumber: "14375177",
      timeStamp: "1642214152",
      hash:
        "0x3d499ef6fe397cf121608aaff9a1c02e863fdacd41afea946f548f1f38c630df",
      nonce: "563",
      blockHash:
        "0xdceb19ad995f0cd0aae6e911744be3c6d3bf81b9e707e710bf0f06f6c1379030",
      from: "0x931b22a138893258c58f3e4143b17086a97862f6",
      contractAddress: "0xb46acb1f8d0ff6369c2f00146897aea1dfcf2414",
      to: "0x6d4d24e50c1bad7df10fafb979de12b6cc6cdac8",
      value: "1023172053263716043052",
      tokenName: "Andromeda V2",
      tokenSymbol: "M31",
      tokenDecimal: "18",
      transactionIndex: "93",
      gas: "215186",
      gasPrice: "5000000000",
      gasUsed: "169374",
      cumulativeGasUsed: "12183067",
      input: "deprecated",
      confirmations: "2285"
    }
  ]
};

//hashes
const hashes = [];
data.result = [
  ...data.result.filter((item) => {
    if (!hashes.includes(item.hash)) {
      hashes.push(item.hash);
      return item;
    }
  })
];
console.log(data.result);
```

@mafortis Please try this. I hope it will work.

> Mutate the result array and add the object that has no duplicated hash
> id

Comment: I am testing it, will let you know about result

Comment: @mafortis yes please

Comment: something is off here, not sure what? see i get 5 api result and creating empty `hashes` array but in my hashes array I get 4, which is correct. But how do I get my loop works based on this hashes and return my data? as you see my data are the results (i will update my code for you)

Comment: Ok i just realised!!! it this code update my `myData[id]` results? so I don't need to make any changes in my loop part? (how does it sum my value values?)

Comment: @mafortis Sorry I didn't get point. do you want to sum the value of duplicated objects also. ? for example two objects have the same hash then they will become 1 object but their 'value' will be equal to sum of value of both objects ?

Comment: That's exactly right

Answer (score 0):

Short and easy to understand code using `lodash`:

```js
data.result = _(data.result)
.groupBy("hash")
.mapValues(arr => ({ ...arr[0], value: String(_.sumBy(arr, i => Number(i.value))) }))
.values()
.valueOf();
```

Other code suggestions here do not sum up the `value` of the array items. They just group/filter the array.

Comment: i think there is one `)` less in your code. Should I put it after `values()` or after `valueOf()`?

Comment: ok i found a bug in your code: i have 2 values from same hash like: `604800000000000000000` and `67200000000000000000` but in results I'm getting this `60480000000000000000067200000000000000000` which means it didn't sum them but put them together, it should do this instead `604800000000000000000 + 67200000000000000000 = xxxxxxxxx(whatever the result is...)`

Comment: Oh, your values are strings. :))) Nice. I've updated the code.